# Custom JAR uploaded to Nexus not resolving from Nexus public group defined in settings.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml, nexus, dependency-management

Issue is manually uploaded artifact to release repository not resolving from Nexus group repository defined in the `settings.xml`.

I've tried including `http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases` repository into the `/nexus/content/groups/public` repository and define group repo path as mirror in the `settings.xml`.

```xml
<settings>
  .......
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>myteam-nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public </url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  .....
</settings>
```

In the Nexus I've below custom JAR as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.xxxx.bank</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxxxxcallws</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.xxxx.bank</groupId>
      <artifactId>xxxxxcallws</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <!-- CHANGE HERE by your team nexus server -->
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <!-- CHANGE HERE by your team nexus server -->
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

When I run the `mvn clean install -U` giving me error saying:

> Could not find artifact com.xxxx.bank:xxxxxcallws:jar:1.0 in myteam-nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)

NOTE: This JAR uploaded into release repository (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases) and I've added same repo into public group repo from Nexus admin UI.

But same way I've added Maven Central proxy in to public group and dependencies from Central is pulling, but the JAR I've uploaded can't find the location via public repository.

Comment: Did you try invalidating cache on the NXRM side in case it (rather than maven) cached a not found?  Do you see the jar in your UI?

Comment: yes jar i can see there in the nexus, since it was uploaded manually

Comment: Did you check the path in NXRM vs what maven is saying?  e.g. can you download http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com.xxxx.bank/xxxxxcallws-1.0.jar via your webbrowser or curl (with proper permissions)?  You'll have to fill in the xxxxx blanks, but hopefully you get my idea=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are uploading the jar manually Nexus add classifier automatically.
Remove the existing jar from nexus and upload it again without classifier.

[image]